# What is default ORM provider in spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm

What is the default ORM provider for spring data if I don't mention about any ORM providers in my configurations?

Comment: hibernate . . .

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is the default Spring JPA implementation.

> Spring Boot configures Hibernate as the default JPA provider.

https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-and-jpa#2-configuration

Answer (score -1):

Spring Data JPA is not a JPA provider. It is a library/framework that adds an extra layer of abstraction on the top of our JPA provider.

Hibernate is a JPA implementation, while Spring Data JPA is a JPA Data Access Abstraction. Spring Data offers a solution to **GenericDao** custom implementations. It can also generate JPA queries on your behalf through method name conventions.

With Spring Data, you may use Hibernate, Eclipse Link, or any other JPA provider

[you should study this blog](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-and-sprin-1)

Comment: That was not the question. He is asking which the default JPA provider.